# Extract text from nodejs using regex

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I have few testcases names which I need to extract. The initial part will be the testcase id and next will be the description. I need to extract the id. For example

```
TC-ABC-98.1.010_1-Verify the layout credit page
TC-RegPMP-1.1.001_2-Verify the [MangerDetails] link is not displayed Admin Page - Name entered
TC-CS8 Customer solution-1.1.001_1-Verify all customer details are shown correctly
TC-USer Review-003-Scenario 1 - Verify User Review Page (User Review section)
```

Above are the titles, and the output I am expecting are :

```
TC-ABC-98.1.010_1
TC-RegPMP-1.1.001_2
TC-CS8 Customer solution-1.1.001_1
TC-USer Review-003-Scenario 1
```

The Solution i tried awas - `/TC-(.*)-/g"` But didnt worked. Can anyone please help

Comment: Look at your log: you're basically just grabbing anything in front of `-Verify`, so just string split on that (although given that very last line, you may need `\s?-\s?Verify`) and then grab `result[0]`.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const sections = [
  'TC-ABC-98.1.010_1-Verify the layout credit page',
  'TC-RegPMP-1.1.001_2-Verify the [MangerDetails] link is not displayed Admin Page - Name entered',
  'TC-CS8 Customer solution-1.1.001_1-Verify all customer details are shown correctly',
  'TC-USer Review-003-Scenario 1 - Verify User Review Page (User Review section)'
];

const extract = (section) =>
  section.match(/^(TC-.+)\s*-\s*(?=Verify)/)?.[1].trim() ?? null;

const extractAll = (sections) => sections.map(extract);

console.log(extractAll(sections));
```

The following returns:

```json
[
  "TC-ABC-98.1.010_1",
  "TC-RegPMP-1.1.001_2",
  "TC-CS8 Customer solution-1.1.001_1",
  "TC-USer Review-003-Scenario 1"
]
```

This also works, and swaps "Verify" for any title-case word.

```js
const sections = [
  'TC-ABC-98.1.010_1-Verify the layout credit page',
  'TC-RegPMP-1.1.001_2-Verify the [MangerDetails] link is not displayed Admin Page - Name entered',
  'TC-CS8 Customer solution-1.1.001_1-Verify all customer details are shown correctly',
  'TC-USer Review-003-Scenario 1 - Verify User Review Page (User Review section)'
];

const extract = (section) =>
  section.match(/^(TC-.+)-(?:|\s-\s)(?=[A-Z][a-z]+)/)?.[1] ?? null

const extractAll = (sections) => sections.map(extract);

console.log(extractAll(sections));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use capture the part before -Verify in a group, and then match -Verify after it:

```
^(TC-.*?)\s*-\s*Verify\b
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(TC-.*?)` Capture **group 1**, match `TC-` followed by any char, as few as possible
- `\s*-\s*` Match `-` between optional whitspace chars
- `Verify\b` Match the word Verify

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/nW9T5X/1).

```js
const regex = /^(TC-.*?)\s*-\s*Verify\b/gm;
const s = `TC-ABC-98.1.010_1-Verify the layout credit page
TC-RegPMP-1.1.001_2-Verify the [MangerDetails] link is not displayed Admin Page - Name entered
TC-CS8 Customer solution-1.1.001_1-Verify all customer details are shown correctly
TC-USer Review-003-Scenario 1 - Verify User Review Page (User Review section)`;

const res = Array.from(s.matchAll(regex), m => m[1]);

console.log(res);
```